# Highest Frequency of Letter(s) in each Line of File-Core Java Programming

Tags: java

StackOverflow people,

Need Java Advice and Code which reads a file(File.txt) and prints to the console a list of all the letters that occurred with the highest frequency in each line of the file, followed by the frequency.

The list of letters should be an alphabetical list of upper case letters followed by an alphabetical list of lower case letters.

---

### Sample Input File(File.txt)

When riding your bicycle backwards down a one-way street, if the
wheel falls of a canoe, how many ball bearings does it take to fill
up a water buffalo?
Hello Howard.

---

### Sample Output

e 6
al 7
a 3
Hlo 2

Sample Code:

```
public class ReadFileFromSystem{

      public static void main(String args[]){
           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/input.txt"));//the file containing lines.
       HashMap<Character,Integer> lettercount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
           int counter =0;


           // string buffer for file reading   
           StringBuffer str;

           // reading line by line from file    
           while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) { 
                // process each characters  
                 for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                          char c = str.charAt(i);                 
                          if (Character.isLetter(c)){
                              if(counter>1){       
                                   counter++;                           
                          }else{
                                 lettercount.put(c,1);                            
                          }                          
                }
           }
           System.out.println("The Alphabet"+c+" has a highest frequency of "+counter); 
     }
```

Comment: Is it a homework? If so, add appropriate tag.

Comment: Do you want advice, or do you want code? (i.e. do you want to learn, or do you just want to copy the code into your assignment?)

Comment: but its not so easy to solve i have tried solving this.how to maintain a data structure for such a complicated process.how will i store the highest frequency of letter(s) in each line of file,i dont think that is straight enough

Comment: i have partically written the codecan u help me further....im stuck ur further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you almost have it.  You need to initialize a new map inside of the `while` loop.  And, you need to use it inside of your `for` loop to collect the data.

You are using only one counter variable.  Instead, you need to use the map to hold multiple counters, one for each character.

The following is psuedo code for what you want to do:

```
for each line in the file:
    initialize an empty Map<String, Integer>
    for each character in the line:
        if the map contains the character:
            increment the count for that char in the map
        else:
            add the character to the map with a count of 1
    iterate through the map and find the highest values, and print their keys
```

Now, you can fairly simply translate each line of psuedo cod into Java, and you will have your answer.

Here, I will help with your inner `for` loop:

```
lettercount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);                 
    if (Character.isLetter(c)){
        if(lettercount.containsKey(c)){       
            lettercount.get(c)++;                         
        }else
            lettercount.put(c,1);                            
    }                          
}
// here we find the max occurances
int maxCount = 0;
for(Integer count: lettercount.values())
    if (count > maxCount) maxCount = count;
// now we find the entries that had that many occurances
String characters = "";
for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry: lettercount.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().equals(maxCount))
        characters += entry.getKey();
}
```

At the end of this, the string `characters` will contain the most repeated chars in the line.  And `maxCount` will contain the count.

Comment: can u alter my code and let me know what mistake i have done,Please i want the answer from my code....Please jjngguy

Comment: @jjnguy,i saw the updates to top of your post.could you paste my code and alter it and show me whats the answer.im struggling to get this end part right.

Comment: @Deepak, I have added an example of what your for loop should look like

Comment: Thanks a lot @jjnguy.u made it possible,Thanks to all Stackoverflow memebers.

Comment: iterate through the map and find the highest values, and print their keys--can you share the code for this part as well

Comment: @jjnguy,Thanks you are simply awesome and superb,I wanted to ask one thin if you guys dont mind,i want to improve in Java Datastructures and algorithms in Java,Could you share some written tutorials/Pdfs/links which could be shared i wantto improve my knowledge.jjnguy can i have your personal email id as well.I want to keep in touch with you too

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- Consider populating a `Map<Character, Integer>` for each line read, whereby the integer value in the map represents the frequency of each character encountered.
- Whilst populating the `Map` you could remember the highest frequency encountered so far (e.g. 5).
- After populating the `Map` you could iterate through its contents and print any letter whose frequency is equal to the highest frequency encountered.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you people please refine my code.Please after this i need help.Im lost